# Obtaining the Taylor Series Method, order two

Tags: taylor-expansion

So here's the problem I'm having trouble with...

The initial value problem:

$$
    x'(t) = \cos(x+t^2)
$$
with $x(-5) = -1$ on the interval $[-5, 3]$.

I have no idea how to star this problem off and need some advice.

I'm looking at a practice example and this is how they did it.

$$ x'(t) = (x+t)^2 $$ and the second derivative is $$ x''(t) = 2(x+t) (x'(t) + 1) $$

I don't understand why they put *x'(t)* into the second derivative...

Comment: For the last point, this is just the chain rule. The derivative with $t$ of $x+t$ is $x'+t'=x'+1$.

Answer (score 0):

We can write

\begin{align*}
x(t+h) &= x(t) + hx^{\prime}(t) + \frac{h^{2}}{2}x^{\prime\prime}(t) + \mathcal{O}(h^{3})\\
& = x(t) + h\cos(x+t^{2}) + \frac{h^{2}}{2}x^{\prime\prime}(t) + \mathcal{O}(h^{3})
\end{align*}

Since 
\begin{align*}
x^{\prime\prime} &= [x^{\prime}]^{\prime}\\
 &= [\cos(x+t^{2})]^{\prime}\\
 &= -2t\sin(x+t^{2})-\sin(x+t^{2})x^{\prime}\\
 &= -2t\sin(x+t^{2}) - \sin(x+t^{2})\cos(x+t^{2})\end{align*}

We get that

$$x(t+h) = x(t) + h\cos(x+t^{2}) + \frac{h^{2}}{2}\left(-2t\sin(x+t^{2}) - \sin(x+t^{2})\cos(x+t^{2})\right) + \mathcal{O}(h^{3})$$

Answer (score 0):

The problem asks to solve the ordinary differential equation

$$x'(t)=cos(x+t^2)$$

in the interval I=[-5, 3] with the the initial value $x(-5)=-1$ by a Taylor series

$$x(t) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_{_i} (t-t_0)^i$$

and to compute the coefficients $a_i, i = 0,1,2$.

The differential equation satisfies a global Lipschitz condition. Hence a unique solution $x(t), t \in I$, exists.

We choose $t_0 = -5$, then $a_0 = -1$. Moreover

$$cos \ z = 1 - (1/2) z^2 + \mathscr O(4)$$

$$t^2 = (t+5)^2 -10(t+5) +25$$

$$x(t) = -1 + a_1(t+5) + \mathscr O(2)$$

$$x'(t) = a_1 +2a_2(t+5) + \mathscr O(2).$$

Comparing coefficients for $x'(t)=cos(x+t^2)$ gives

$$x'(t) = 1 -(1/2)[-1 + a_1(t+5) -10(t+5) +25]^2 + \mathscr O(2)$$

$$x'(t) = 1 -(1/2)[24 + (a_1-10)(t+5) ]^2 + \mathscr O(2)$$

$$x'(t) = 1 -(1/2)[24^2 + 48(a_1-10)(t+5) + \mathscr O(2)]$$

$$a_1 +2a_2(t+5) + \mathscr O(2) = -287 -24(a_1-10)(t+5) + \mathscr O(2).$$

Comparing coefficients on both sides gives

$$a_1 = -287, a_2 = 3564.$$